# Heatmap do not display row and column names

Tags: r

I am stuck with displaying row and column names using this code. Rather showing names it is showing numbers.

```
data <- read.csv("/Users/apple/Documents/42_heatmap_new.csv", sep=",")

mat_data <- data.matrix(data[,2:ncol(data)])

heatmaply(mat_data, file="heatmaply_preformed.html", dendrogram = "none", 
  plot_method= c("plotly"), margins = c(150,250,30,150), grid_gap = 0.1, 
  show_grid = TRUE, xlab = "Antibiotics", ylab = "Clinical isolates", 
  main="Heatmap for drug resistance profile of 42 isolates", cexCol = 0.9, 
  cexRow = 1.0, lwid =c(4,1), RowV=NA, Colv=NA, lhei =c(2,2))
```

Comment: Could you edit this as a reproducible example (eg can you do it using one of the example datasets built into R; or use dput to put your data into the question)?

Comment: I think you probably need to use `heatmapr(mat_data)` don't you?  And from looking at the helpfile, maybe you also need to first assign `row.names(data) <- whatevercolumn`

Comment: No, heatmapr(mat_data) does not work.

Comment: Have you tried assigning row.names to the data?  Thiss wont' be done automatically by `read.csv`, you need to do it with `row.names(data) <- data$names_column` or similar.